# Issue related to Kandy WebRTC

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, webrtc

I am trying to implement WebRTC p2p communication for my business model and I am using Kandy (https://www.kandy.io/) service for the same

I have tried to implement the Video call feature. I have used the code available in the [tutorial](https://developer.kandy.io/tutorials/javascript/ip-calls) and have hosted the files over HTTPS, the call gets established but I don't find any communication happening (Both audio and video) , I tried the same code in Codepen the call works fine there. I don't undertstand what the issue is ?

Is there any standards that are to be met for the SSL or any server requirements are present to implement WebRTC ?

Comment: You either have HTTPS or you don't. While there are internal differentiations with several possible protocol versions/cyphers, that's nothing WebRTC should/would care about.

Comment: Can you share your code, i will help you